# fetch error while installing capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

Platform: Ubuntu 12.10 x386
Env: Ruby 2.1.0 Rails 4.1.0 Rubygems 2.2.2

I am trying to install capybara gem and throw 503 error ! I have tried to change source of rubygems but the error persist. please show me the workaround ! Thanks

```
       robus@lucy:~$ gem install capybara-webkit
       ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
       bad response Service Unavailable 503 (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=capybara)
```

Comment: There were some problems with Rubygems dependency API. Try again.

Comment: @MarekLipka: For me it works on local Mac, but does not on remote Ubuntu